# Run Visual Studio Load Tests in Microsoft Azure from build

Tags: visual-studio, azure, build, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I know that it is possible to run Load Tests within *Azure* manually. But is it possible to run *Visual Studio* Load Tests in *Azure* from build?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is a code sample...

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Cloud-Load-Testing-API-b333e778

Comment: I will look into this, it looks like a heavy coding